# How to clear cache in Qlik Sense desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, qliksense

I've been debugging a button extension issue for a button that does not work on only a few user's local machines. Over the past couple of days, I've narrowed the problem to the user's cache. With that, the bug is easily replicable.

Clearing the cache and loading the Qlik app in Google Chrome at localhost:4848/hub, the app's buttons will work. However, the app will continue to not work in the Qlik Sense desktop application itself. Because Qlik Sense is a skin over Chromium, I figured a simple reset of its cache will fix the bug for the few users that are experiencing this. Unfortunately, I'm unable to find a solution specifically for Qlik Sense via both Google and the Qlik Community Forums.

- Is clearing the cache in the desktop application possible? If so, how do I go about it?
- Scouring the Community Forums and Google, it appears a GUI interface to clear cache *once existed*, but now doesn't. If so, was it deprecated?

Thank y'all!

Comment: This is still not solved –Nov 15th, 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Chrome` is involved then the default shortcuts will work. The shortcut below will reload the page ignoring the cache

[image: Chrome shortcut]

This is from [Google's support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB) (`Web page shortcut` section)

If you want to be more "brutal" :) you can manually delete the content you don't want through the `Chrome Dev tools`:

- on the page, in QS Desktop, with the dashboard press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Mouse right click`
- this should bring the context menu
- select `Show DevTools`
- navigate to `Resources` tab
- expand `Session Storage`
- you should see only one item `http://localhost:4848`. Click it
- on the right side you will see all entries in `Key <-> Value` format (probably you have only one)
- right-click on it and press `Delete`
- refresh the page (`F5`)

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea you could load dev tools in the Qlik app itself. 

All items were present when I did this on the user's computer. Unfortunately it didn't work. I did both steps multiple times, rebooting Qlik and the button is still not functioning. However, it still functions in localhost:4848 in Chrome. Any ideas?

I really appreciate the time you're putting in to help me, Stefan. Is there any information I can provide you?

Comment: Possible to delete the object and add it again?

Comment: I've had him redownload the app (which works) several times. Would deleting the buttons individually and readding them help?

Comment: You can try with one button for start. re-adding the button will generate new object id internally which will technically clear the saved data for this button (basically there will be no data for this object id)

Comment: Alright, I'll have him try that and report back to you! Thank you again!